# Why increasing Lasso regression alpha value the root mean squared error only increases?

Tags: regression, linear-model, lasso

Hi i am fitting a Lasso model using different values in the range of 2*10^-5 to 500 for the alpha parameters like:

```
alphas=np.linspace(0.00002,500,20)
```

when i plot the negative root mean squared error and absolute error from cross validation i get a graph like this:
[image]

so the error increases in modulo instead of decreasing... why am i getting this result?

Comment: By *definition* of "least squares," the RMS error *must* be least when $\alpha=0$ because it is directly proportional to the sum of the squares of the error--which is precisely the quantity being minimized.

Comment: yes but from what i understand for lasso in this case since the graph is the error i get from cross validation, it should decrease in the module up to a certain alpha value and then increase again or i am wrong?

Comment: Were you expecting it to decrease?  Larger $\alpha$ means stronger penalization and less model freedom, hence increased RMS error.  And an aside: you'll probably see more interesting behavior setting $\alpha$ less than one.  The algorithm may be scaling the data so that larger values result in a completely empty model.

Comment: For some examples of what these plots typically look like, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319861 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/488675.  The latter looks like it might ask the same question you are.

Comment: I just saw your comment--I think the result will make more sense using a range of smaller $\alpha$ values.  It looks to me like you overshot the the decrease.

Comment: as increasing alpha i am reducing the variance and increasing the bias i would expect the RMSE for cross validation to decrease up to a certain value of alpha and then re- increase due to high bias

Comment: @abstrusiosity  yes exactly if i choose alpha values in the order of 10^-5 the behaviuor is correct... but then i don't know if it makes sense having an alpha equal to 10^-5